# Trying to implement react-intersection-observer inside react-grid-layout with no luck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout, react-intersection-observer

I have a page where there are around 10-15 cards fetching data from APIs and printing graphs. When I load the page they all start fetching data and render a graph which is making page little lagging as obvious.

As a part performance optimization I am trying to implement react-intersection-observer package so only card visible on screen will call APIs and show graph. But that seems to be not working, there is no error so not able to find what's wrong.

If I just comment

```
<GridLayout
    className="layout"
    layout={layout}
    cols={12}
    rowHeight={100}
    width={800}
>
```

and

```
</GridLayout>
```

Then everything works fine, But not with it

I tried 2-3 different approaches but so far no luck, any help would be appreciated.

**[Here is the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-card-antd-4-24-6-forked-sy83xp?file=/demo.js)**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the reason might be [`Card`](https://ant.design/components/card#api) from `antd` does not forward `ref`, while `ref` is needed for either `react-intersection-observer` or `react-grid-layout` to function.

While there is no official guide to keep these libraries work together, perhaps the `<InView/>` component provided by `react-intersection-observer` could be a possible approach, since it accepts `forwardRef`, and can serve as a wrapper component for `Card`, while it functions as the observer as well.

Potential drawbacks of this approach include `<InView />` would be an extra wrapper for `Card`, which might or might not be a problem depending on the use case.

Forked demo with the experimental approach: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-card-antd-4-24-6-forked-s9iwso?file=/demo.js)

`Card` with the implementation is separated as a custom component to keep the parent cleaner. The `onChange` property on `<InView />` can accept a callback to run what is needed when the component is in view.

A state `isInView` is defined here just for testing, and I think a custom state would probably be a more suitable approach here than using the render props, which is limited inside `<InView />` and also depends on `ref` to function.

The props forwarded to the custom component are required by `react-grid-layout` according to their [document](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#custom-child-components-and-draggable-handles).

```
const MyCard = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      style,
      className,
      onMouseDown,
      onMouseUp,
      onTouchEnd,
      children,
      ...props
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    //  For testing only
    const [isInView, setIsInView] = useState(false);

    return (
      <InView
        threshold={0.3}
        //  For testing, accepts callback to run when in view
        onChange={(inView, entry) => setIsInView(inView)}
        ref={ref}
        style={{ ...style }}
        className={className}
        onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
        onTouchEnd={onTouchEnd}
      >
        <Card
          title="Small size card"
          style={{
            height: "100%",
            border: isInView ? "5px solid hotpink" : "1px solid blue",
          }}
        >
          <h2>{`30% inside viewport: ${isInView}.`}</h2>
          <p>Card content</p>
        </Card>
        {children}
      </InView>
    );
  }
);
```

Parent component now only include any logic to define `layout`:

```
const App = () => {
  const layout = [
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 8, h: 8 },
    { i: "b", x: 0, y: 5, w: 8, h: 8 },
    { i: "c", x: 0, y: 10, w: 8, h: 8 },
    { i: "d", x: 0, y: 10, w: 8, h: 8 },
    { i: "e", x: 0, y: 10, w: 8, h: 8 },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <GridLayout
        className="layout"
        layout={layout}
        cols={12}
        rowHeight={100}
        width={800}
      >
        {/*  Experimental approach */}
        {layout.map((each) => (
          <MyCard key={each.i || Math.random()} />
        ))}
      </GridLayout>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

On a side note, because `<InView />` is already wired up with the required functionalities, the wrapped `Card` from `antd` could be replaced by a custom component with necessary styles, if preferred.

Comment: Yes like you said, Card component is not passing ref, So what I did is Insead of wrapping whole card I wrapped card contents in `inView`, and its working fine, Along with all other features provided by `react-grid-layout`